# Laravel - Problema al intentar hacer un "route cache" con el comando artisan

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-blade, laravel-6

tengo un problema al realizar el comando php artisan route:cache, hago este comando porque no me coje unos parametros del .env (no se si esto afecta) y a raiz de esto he decidido lanzar todo tipo de cache.

Los archivos de rutas api.php y web.php los tengo tal como esto

**api.php**

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

/**
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
 **/

Route::middleware(['checkIp'])->group(function () {

    Route::get('coches', 'Api\CochesController@index')->name('api.taller-servicios.index');
    Route::get('coches/{id}', 'Api\CochesController@show')->name('api.taller-servicios.show');
    Route::put('coches/{id}', 'Api\CochesController@update')->name('api.taller-servicios.update');

});
```

**Archivo web.php**

```
    <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('welcome')
    ->middleware(\App\Http\Middleware\CheckAuth::class);


Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('login')
    ->middleware(\App\Http\Middleware\CheckAuth::class);

Route::get('/signin', 'AuthController@signin')->name('signin');
Route::get('/authorize', 'AuthController@gettoken');
Route::get('/logout', 'AuthController@logout');
```

La respuesta que tengo al ejecutar el comando es esta.

> C:\xampp\htdocs\site_pruebas>php artisan route:cache

```
Route cache cleared!

   LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [/] for serialization. Uses Closure.

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\site_pruebas\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:917
    913|      */
    914|     public function prepareForSerialization()
    915|     {
    916|         if ($this->action['uses'] instanceof Closure) {
  > 917|             throw new LogicException("Unable to prepare route [{$this->uri}] for serialization. Uses Closure.");
    918|         }
    919| 
    920|         $this->compileRoute();
    921| 

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Routing\Route::prepareForSerialization()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\site_pruebas\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand.php:62

  2   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand::handle()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\site_pruebas\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:32

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.

C:\xampp\htdocs\site_pruebas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Route Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#route-caching)

> Las rutas basadas en cierre no se pueden almacenar en caché. Para utilizar el almacenamiento en caché de rutas, debe convertir cualquier ruta de cierre a clases de controlador.

Tendrías que pasar la lógica de estas dos rutas [basadas en cierre (o función anónima)](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#basic-routing) a un controlador para poder generar el cache de rutas:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('welcome')
    ->middleware(\App\Http\Middleware\CheckAuth::class);


Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('login')
    ->middleware(\App\Http\Middleware\CheckAuth::class);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo ví.