# Laravel LogicException : Unable to prepare route [/] for serialization

Tags: php, laravel

Al borrar el caché de mi proyecto Laravel con el comando php artisan route:cache, me aparece el siguiente mensaje y no puedo continuar:
*LogicException : Unable to prepare route [/] for serialization.*

Esta es la ruta:

```
Route::get('/', function() { 
 $active_page = 'Inicio';

 return redirect()->route('login');
});
```

Probe comentando el siguiente codigo en api.php :

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) { 
 return $request->user(); 
});
```

Pero el problema persiste.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Laravel - Problema al intentar hacer un "route cache" con el comando artisan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/343830/laravel-problema-al-intentar-hacer-un-route-cache-con-el-comando-artisan)

Comment: Es por usar closures en la ruta '/' https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/343830/laravel-problema-al-intentar-hacer-un-route-cache-con-el-comando-artisan